# Как передать переменную из сидера в factory?

Tags: php, laravel

У меня в сидере есть цикл:

```
public function run()
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < 100; ++$i) {
        CharacterEpisode::factory()->count(3)->create(['title' => $i]);
    }

}
```

Я хочу переменную $i передать в factory:

```
public function definition($title)
{
        return [
            'character_id' => $title,
            'episode_id' => $this->faker->unique()->numberBetween($min = 1, $max = 30),
        ];
}
```

Но у меня выдает ошибку:

> Declaration of
> Database\Factories\CharacterEpisodeFactory::definition($title) must be
> compatible with
> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory::definition()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В фабрике вы указываете значения "по умолчанию" для всех атрибутов. Если нужно их переопределить, то передаете соответствующий массив. Читать тут: [Переопределение атрибутов](https://laravel.com/docs/master/database-testing#overriding-attributes)

То есть, в сиде будет так:

```
public function run()
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < 100; ++$i) {
        CharacterEpisode::factory()->count(3)->create(['character_id' => $i]);
    }

}
```

А из фабрики убрать `$title`.

Comment: А что написать вместо title? Чему приравнять поле 'character_id'?

Comment: `$title` из фабрики убрать. Если фабрика сама не определяет значение для `character_id`, то тоже убрать. Когда в фабрику передадите массив `['character_id' => $i]`, он наложится на тот, что в фабрике (то, чего нет, дополнится, то, что есть, заменится). [Переопределение атрибутов](https://docs.rularavel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#overriding-attributes)